# How can I Authorize an existing Project in VS Code

Tags: vs-code

I am new to VSCode and and trying to switch from Eclipse and this is becoming already painful.My end goal is to reconnect an existing project I already created with an existing Sandbox.
I already created the project and did some work. Then I had to witch to another org and I created a new project, but now I need to switch back to my original Project and Org.
So What I did is in VSCode I selected File - Open Folder, and selected my project. But now I need to authorize. When I hit Ctrl+Shift+P and type sfdx, I do not see the sfdx Authorize Org. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have the `sfdx-cli` and `sfdx` VS Code extension installed correctly? Can you post a screenshot of the successful installation of both please so we can help you better?

Comment: Yes, I do. I was able to create 3 project from scratch for 3 different sandboxes with no problems. But, now I am trying to go back to my 1st project and I can not.

Comment: try to run some other command related to sfdx. It will start activating the extensions. Once the sfdx extension got activated, You will get option to set the default org

Comment: Ok, so now I get this message: No sfdx-project.json found in the root directory of your open project. Open a Salesforce DX project in VS Code.
When I go under the project folder, I do see the sfdx-project.jason file in there

Comment: Make sure you have the correct folder open. It must be exactly in the folder you open, not any sub-folder. It's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: One easy way to tell is to press Ctrl/Cmd-Shift-C (Open New Terminal) and then `ls -la` or `dir`. You should see sfdx-project.json listed here. If not, you've got the wrong folder open.

Comment: That was exactly it. I had a folder for the project name and a subfolder with the same exact name. Once I selected the subfolder all worked as expected. It is quite strange that when I selected the top folder all my LWC and classes loaded in the VS Code. I would expect nothing to load until the correct folder is selected.